# If $A,B$ are subgroups of the group $G$, then $A\cup B\leq G\Leftrightarrow (A\subseteq B \vee B\subseteq A)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here's the problem and my solution. Please check if the solution to part two is right and give me a hint about the subgroup-ness of $A\cup B\cup C$. Thanks.

**Problem:** If $A,B$ are subgroups of a group $G$, prove that $A\cup B$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $A\subseteq B \vee B\subseteq A$. If $C$ is also a subgroup of $G$, does a similar necessary and sufficient condition hold for $A\cup B\cup C$ to be a subgroup of $G$?

**My Solution:**

$(\Leftarrow)$ If $A\subseteq B$, then $B=A\cup B\leq G$, because $B\leq G$.

If $B\subseteq A$, then $A=A\cup B\leq G$, because of the similar reason.

$(\Rightarrow)$ $A\cup B\leq G \Rightarrow A\cup B\subseteq G$.

If $A\subseteq B$, then the proof is complete. Let $A\nsubseteq B\Rightarrow \begin{cases} A\cap B=\emptyset \\ A\cap B\subset A \mbox{ and } A\cap B\subset B \end{cases}$

If $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then since $A,B\leq G$ separately, $A$ and $B$ will each have a unique identity element. But, $A\cup B\leq G$ so $A\cup B$ needs a unique identity element where it has two which is a contradiction, yielding $A\cap B\ne \emptyset$.

If $A\cap B\subset A\mbox{ and } B$, then according to a theorem, $A\cap B\leq G$ but that also comes to a contradiction when $\mbox{Identity element }=e\in A\backslash B$ (Because $A\cap B$ won't have an identity element anymore to be a group).

$\square$

Comment: I don't get your last point "but that also comes to a contradiction" - Why ? Both $A$ and $B$ have the same identity element and that's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Assume that $A\cup B$ is a group such that $A\not\subset B$ and $B\not \subset A$ so take $a\in A\setminus B$ and $b\in B\setminus A$ and consider $c=a+b\in A\cup B$. Can you find a contradiction